# Why activity not show when click on the notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm writing push notification in Android project,in the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` service write this code for show the notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationMessage.class); // 
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(currentapiVersion)
    .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify((int) notificatioId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

when main activity show,and send the push,notification is show and click on the redirect to the `NotificationMessage` activity,but when i close the main activity,and send push again,notification show to me,but when i click on that,redirect to main activity and don't show the `NotificationMessage` activity,what happen?how can i solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void setNotification(String notificationMessage) {
    mNotificationManager  = getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationMessage.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(currentapiVersion)
.setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new 
 NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify((int) notificatioId, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: what is mNotificationManager  ?

Comment: what is requestID?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
Button btn_notifcation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_notifcation= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn_notifcation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addNotification();
        }
    });

}


private void addNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
                    .setContentText("This is a test notification");


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationMessage.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

}
```

Comment: what is mNotificationManager?

Comment: by using mNotificationManager you can show notification into the titlebar of your application

Comment: thanks,but when my app in background,and your code run,dont show NotificationMessage activity

Comment: I have update my answer.. and this code is working for me.. please check this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setNumber(messageCount)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: did you test your code?when my app in background,not work